# Angularjs sorting in descending order

Tags: angularjs

```
{
"35": "testing",
"46": "tst123",
"51": "alpha_circular",
"56": "test4",
"60": "alpha_price",
"64": "test_attached",
"70": "test789",
"71": "new cir",
"73": "valid"
 }
```

I need to sort the above data in descending order based on the key. How can I achieve it?

Also I have used `ng-repeat="(id,value)"` in lists track by **$index**". Can I apply filters in this case?

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: Why do you return ids as a String? Try to return without quotes and OrderBy with -id will work

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found the orderBy works only with array. So you'll have to change the JSON.

Comment: for this I'll have to restructure my json data. Is there any way I can do it on the data that i have specified above

Answer (score 0):

Not an `Angular` solution. Just `JS` solution to sort `Object` with keys.

```js
var obj = {
"35": "testing",
"46": "tst123",
"51": "alpha_circular",
"56": "test4",
"60": "alpha_price",
"64": "test_attached",
"70": "test789",
"71": "new cir",
"73": "valid"
 };

function comparator(a, b){
  return b-a;
}

Object.keys(obj).sort(comparator).forEach(function(key, i) {
  console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: I want in descending order

Comment: Updated answer, just logged the values in `descending` order

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.data = {
"35": "testing",
"46": "tst123",
"51": "alpha_circular",
"56": "test4",
"60": "alpha_price",
"64": "test_attached",
"70": "test789",
"71": "new cir",
"73": "valid"
 };
  
  $scope.array = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data,function(d,i){
    $scope.array.push({id:i,value:d});
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in array | orderBy:'-id'">
            {{value.value}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following solution

In your html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in keys() | orderBy:'-key'">
            <li>{{item.key}} :: {{item.value}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your controller

```
function FooController($scope) {

  $scope.keys = function(){
      var keysList = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key) {
        keysList.push({"key": parseInt(key), "value": value});
      });
      return keysList
  }
$scope.items = {
  "35": "testing",
  "46": "tst123",
  "51": "alpha_circular",
  "56": "test4",
  "60": "alpha_price",
  "64": "test_attached",
  "70": "test789",
  "71": "new cir",
  "73": "valid"
```

}
}

Output should be

```
73 :: valid
71 :: new cir
70 :: test789
64 :: test_attached
60 :: alpha_price
56 :: test4
51 :: alpha_circular
46 :: tst123
35 :: testing
```

Hope this is help you.

Comment: I want in descending order

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below solution hope its the right alternative:

Firstly I reversed the keys using,
$scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.obj).reverse();

And then in my view
`<div ng-repeat="key in keys">
    {{obj[key]}}
</div>`

Let me know if its the right way!!